# Phonegap/Cordova Android doesn't show the splash screen when re-launch after navigator.app.exitApp()

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, android-5.0-lollipop, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I'm developing with Cordova 5.1.1 mixed Jquery mobile 1.4.5 and Backbonejs 1.2.2.

At now, I'm facing a problem:

When cordova app is exited by navigator.app.exitApp(), then re-launch it from the recent apps stack, the splash screen doesn't show - I have tested on android lollipop 5.0 & 5.1. So this is the cause of showing unexpected app load state (there is no a splash screen to show up, cordova app is opened immediately while js, css files is loaded incompletely. It causes to show a broken page layout for 1 second before the page is loaded completely)

Note: the splash screen still shows up as expected when cordova app was removed from the recent apps stack before re-launch it.

**Edit**: Thank to **dsokurenko**.Following the link that he answered my question, I solved the problem:

It's look like a bug of 2.1.0 version of cordova-plugin-splashscreen, I downgraded the cordova-plugin-splashscreen version from 2.1.0 to 2.0.0, and then the splashscreen showed up as expected.

Comment: This seems to be a known bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9374